# How does Ember Data update the model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I don't understand how ember data updates the model, if you do this

```
model: function() {
   return this.store.find('something');
}
```

You're not actually giving it any reference to the model, so how does it update or how does it know what to update when it gets the result back from the server?

Answer (score 1):

That particular example is actually requesting a collection (all) of `something`.

If you are looking for a particular record you would do `this.store.find('something', id)` where id is some unique identifier.

`this.store.find('something', 3)`

`this.store.find('something', "cool_post")`

```
App.Something = DS.Model.extend({
   someAttr = DS.attr()
});

var promise = this.store.find('something', 2);
promise.then(function(record){
  //promise is resolved and the record is ready here
  console.log(record.get('someAttr'));
}
```

find will always return a promise.  Ember Data will then asynchronously search it's cache or make a call to the server (or fixture data depending on your adapter).  Once the data has return it will then create an instance of `something` (defined above).  It will then use the serializer associated with the adapter used and apply the results to the instance of `something`.

The format your json should come in is like so:

```
{
  "something": {
    "id": 1
    "someAttr": "Rails is omakase"
   }
}
```

The model hook is a special hook in that if you return a promise to it it will wait and resolve that promise and use the result of the promise instead of the promise for the model of the controller.

See the ember data transition document for additional information: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question is how does it update the model after it gets the result from the server.

Comment: Gotcha, I wasn't quite sure what portion you are talking about, here's a larger shotgun shot.

Comment: So, really it has nothing to do with ember-data then, Ember is the one that works with the promise?

Comment: Correct, but it's important to note it's on the model hook only. That's the only hook that will handle the resolution of the promise and use the result of the promise as the model instead of the promise as the model.